# Entity Framework Duplicate Entries and Auto Propertie filling

Tags: c#, entity-framework, duplicates

I have the following two classes

```
[Serializable]
public partial class DocumentType
{
    public DocumentType()
    {
        this.Documents = new List<Document>();
    }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Document> Documents { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
[Serializable]
public partial class Document
{
    public Document()
    {
    }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public byte[] Data { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> TypeIDfk { get; set; }
    public virtual DocumentType DocumentType { get; set; 
}
```

I make use of a Client-Server Architecture and using Sockets I send a list of all the DocumentTypes over the Network into a Combobox
On SelectionChanged in the Combobox I set the 
DocumentType = Selected DocumentType
and Also the TypeIDfk to DocumentType.ID

The Problem I have is when I send the Document over the Network back to the Server and it saves it into the Database it creates a Duplicate Entry into DocumentType. and then changes TypeIDfk

I solved it by setting DocumentType = null ( but leave the TypeIDfk ), this is bad because of Binding I want to Display. also that doesn't bother me too much I can do the following
TypeIDfk to DocumentType.ID
Send and Save
DocumentType = Selected DocumentType

However this is where it gets funny.
I did the following
this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

Now after I called SaveChanges() when I inserted Document into the DbSet
the Document.DocumentType gets filled Automatically. (even tho it was null)
I dont want that I want to stay null after Inserted so I can change it again on ClientSide.

But it would be great if Someone can help me solve the Issue on the Duplicate Entries.
I have around 64 Classes for my project at university going through each Insertforms to check where duplicates rise will take me a week or more :/

Thanks for any response

Comment: It is useful to post the saving method to show how you store entities on the server. But possible problem may be like this: you add a Document to it's DBSet, then the state of the document in the context changes to "Added". The same happens for the entire graph associated with this entity so the state of all of them changes to Added. When you try to save changes the DocumentType are also go to be inserted while they already exist in DB. The solution: simply change the state of DocumentType entities to UnChanged. It is done by using ChangeTracker.

Comment: I just use the .Add() and then SaveChanges. cool will take a look at the ChangeTracker I think this will be used at atleast 15 Classes as they are only types or catagories.

Comment: Remember in a N-Layer disconnected application you should know the correct state of the entities which are to be attached to the context and you should tell the context to correct them if necessary.